# Change SpecFlow+ runner report output link

Tags: specflow, specrun

We are using Jenkins in our build cycle to run our specflow tests. We are trying to find a better way to surface the test results. The generated html report file is great, but right now we have to manually log into the build server to check it out. I want to surface that file via a clickable link.

Here is what I am talking about specifically. Here is the test results via our Jenkins console
[image]

I want to change the highlighted text to an http url so that everyone can just click that and view the file.

I already have the http link working, so that's not the issue. I just need to figure out how to make specrun output this link here.

Any ideas on if this is possible? And if so how to do it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is currently not possible in SpecFlow+Runner, but I will put it on the backlog as a feature request.

Perhaps you can do something in Jenkins to parse the output and reformat the link.

Full disclosure: I am on of the developers of the SpecFlow+Runner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that would be an awesomely useful feature when/if  it becomes available. As for now, we will look into parsing the output from Jenkins. Thanks for you time.